# how does C3 algorithm for mro in python work?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

consider the following code:

```
class A: pass
class B(A): pass        
class C(A): pass
class D(A): pass
class E(B,C): pass
class F(B,D): pass
class G(C,D): pass
class H(E,F,G): pass
```

I get the following ordering for `class H`:

```
H.mro() -> H, E, F, B, G, C, D, A, object
```

Why is `B` before `G` in this case, since `H` inherits directly from `G`and only indirectly from `B`?

Comment: This is really well documented [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Comment: It's like topological sorting.

Answer (score 4):

The way C3 works is well documented [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). But we can work through it for your specific example to see why you get the result you do.

The linearization algorithm is not too hard to understand. It has two recursive parts. The public interface I'll call `mro` (the doc above uses `L[x]` instead of `mro(x)`, but I'll stick to Python-ish syntax). The other part is a helper function called `merge`.

The `mro` function is very easy to understand. It returns `[object]` in the base case where that's when it's called on the `object` type, or it returns a list with its argument first, followed by the values returned by `merge` called on the `mro`s of all the bases of its argument. Here's a quick and dirty implementation in Python:

```
def mro(cls):
    if cls is object:
        return [object]
    return [cls] + merge([mro(base) for base in cls.__bases__])
```

Merge is a little bit more complicated. Its argument is a list of lists, each being the `mro` of a base class. If there's just one list, the result of the `merge` is really easy (it's just the same list). That 's the single inheritance case. But that behavior doesn't need any special case code that, it will emerge from the algorithm. The algorithm says to scan the lists you were passed in order to find the first valid value to put into the result mro. A valid value is one that only appears at the start of of the argument lists it is in, never deeper in the list. Once you have a valid value, you put it at the head of your results, then recurse on the rest of each list (excluding the value you just extracted).

Here's a Python implementation of that too:

```
def merge(mros):
    if not any(mros): # all lists are empty
        return []  # base case
    for candidate, *_ in mros:
        if all(candidate not in tail for _, *tail in mros):
            return [candidate] + merge([tail if head is candidate else [head, *tail]
                                        for head, *tail in mros])
    else:
        raise TypeError("No legal mro")
```

The list comprehension to create the list of lists argument to `merge` is a bit tricky. It's just removing references to `candidate` that appear at the start of the lists, and discarding any lists that wind up empty afterwards (so we can know when to stop recursing).

Anyway, lets look at how these functions handle your class hierarchy, when you call `mro(H)`.

The first call is to `mro(H)`, which runs the general case of the `mro` function's code. This results in three recursive calls, to get the `mro`s of `E`, `F` and `G`. Hopefully those don't confuse you, as I don't really want to dive into them (as the part of the algorithm causing the oddity you're asking about comes later). So after those recursive `mro` calls resolve, we call `merge` on the results. This as our call stack:

```
mro(H)->
   return [H] + merge([[E, B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
```

The `merge` code now runs. The first candidate it checks is `E`, and it's a valid one, since `E` doesn't appear anywhere other than at the head of a list. So it removes `E` and recurses. New call stack:

```
mro(H)->
   [H] + merge([[E, B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[E, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [E] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
```

On the next run it first tries `B` as a candidate, but it's no good since it appears second in the second list. So it goes on to try `F`, which is valid:

```
mro(H)->
   [H] + merge([[E, B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[E, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [E] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[B, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [F] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
```

This next call is the interesting one, for your question. The first candidate to be tested in the `merge` code is `B`, since its the head of the first list. It turns out to be valid this time, since it is the head of the second list too (rather than the tail as last time), and isn't in the third list at all. So it's the result that's removed before the recursion, rather than `G` (as you seem to have expected).

```
mro(H)->
   [H] + merge([[E, B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[E, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [E] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[B, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [F] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[B, ...], [B, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [B] + merge([[C, A, object], [D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
```

From here things are pretty simple, as the values in the third list will end up getting removed one by one (with those that are in the earlier lists also going at the same time). I'll just show the call stack rather than commenting on each one:

```
mro(H)->
   [H] + merge([[E, B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[E, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [E] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [F, B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[B, ...], [F, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [F] + merge([[B, C, A, object], [B, D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[B, ...], [B, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [B] + merge([[C, A, object], [D, A, object], [G, C, D, A, object]])
merge([[C, ...], [D, ...], [G, ...]]) ->
   [G] + merge([[C, A, object], [D, A, object], [C, D, A, object]])
merge([[C, ...], [D, ...], [C, ...]]) ->
   [C] + merge([[A, object], [D, A, object], [D, A, object]])
merge([[A, ...], [D, ...], [D, ...]]) ->
   [D] + merge([[A, object], [A, object], [A, object]])
merge([[A, object], [A, object], [A, object]]) ->
   [A] + merge([[object], [object], [object]])
merge([[object], [object], [object]]) ->
   [object] + merge([])
merge([]) -> 
   []   # base case
```

Comment: In the doc link you gave the algorithm was `L[C(B1 ... BN)] = C + merge(L[B1] ... L[BN], B1 ... BN)`, but what your code implements seems to be `C + merge(L[B1] ... L[BN])`. They seem not to be equivalent or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately C3 doesn't care about *directly* or *indirectly*. It cares about:

- *local precedence ordering*:

  With `class H(E,F,G)`, MRO of `H` must have `E` before `F` before `G`.
- *monotonicity*:

  With `class H(E,F,G)`, MRO of `E` and MRO of `F` and MRO of `G` must be kept in MRO of `H`.

C3 is actually very simple: Build a directed graph using these constraints and run topological sort on it.